# Set no password for a local user

Tags: powershell

I need to know if there is any way to leave an existing local user without a password using PowerShell.

Comment: Too broad. Have you at least tried searching this up or looking for answers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Set-LocalUser -name test -Password ([securestring]::new())
```

will set the account "test" to have a blank password.